# System.Windows.data.error : 4

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

I tried all day to make a wpf error disappear without success.

Here is the template/style for my combobox :

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
        <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/BPM2016;component/#Open Sans Condensed" />
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground"  Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexteBouton}"/>
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexteBouton}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBouton}" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource FontSizeSmall}" />
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Left"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                    <Border
                        Name="Border"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                        BorderBrush="{x:Null}"
                        CornerRadius="7"
                        BorderThickness="0"
                        Padding="2,2,2,2">
                        <ContentPresenter
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.ContentTemplate}"
                            Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}" />
                    </Border>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="Border" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBoutonHover}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexteBoutonHover}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="Border" Value="0"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexteBoutonDisabled}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <Style  x:Key="StyleComboBox"  TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
        <Setter Property="Cursor" Value="Hand" />
        <Setter Property="Height" Value="25" />
        <Setter Property="UIElement.SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
        <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurSecondaire}"/>
        <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurTexteBouton}" />
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurBouton}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{DynamicResource CouleurSecondaire}" />
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="/BPM2016;component/#Open Sans Condensed" />
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="{DynamicResource FontSizeNormal}" />
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">
                    <Grid Background="Transparent">
                        <ToggleButton
                ClickMode="Press"
                Name="ToggleButton"
                IsChecked="{Binding Path=IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                Focusable="False"
                Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxToggleButtonTemplate}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Margin="7,2,25,0"
                Name="ContentSite"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItemTemplate}"
                Content="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.SelectionBoxItem}"
                IsHitTestVisible="False"
                            />
                        <TextBox
                Margin="3,3,23,3"
                Visibility="Hidden"
                HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                Name="PART_EditableTextBox"
                Background="Transparent"
                VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Style="{x:Null}"
                IsReadOnly="True"
                Focusable="True"
                xml:space="preserve"
                Template="{StaticResource ComboBoxTextBoxTemplate}"/>
            <Popup
                Placement="Bottom"
                Name="Popup"
                Focusable="False"
                IsOpen="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen}"
                PopupAnimation="Slide">
              <Grid
                  MinWidth="{TemplateBinding FrameworkElement.ActualWidth}"
                  MaxHeight="{TemplateBinding ComboBox.MaxDropDownHeight}"
                  Background="Transparent"
                  Name="DropDown"
                  SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
                <Border
                    BorderBrush="{StaticResource CouleurBouton}"
                    BorderThickness="0,0,0,2"
                    CornerRadius="7"
                    Name="DropDownBorder"
                    Cursor="Hand"
                    Background="{StaticResource CouleurBouton}"/>
                <ScrollViewer  Style="{StaticResource FavsScrollViewerAutre}"
                    Margin="4,6,4,6"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True">

                  <ItemsPresenter
                      KeyboardNavigation.DirectionalNavigation="Contained" />
                </ScrollViewer>
              </Grid>
            </Popup>
          </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.HasItems" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="FrameworkElement.MinHeight" TargetName="DropDownBorder" Value="95"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CouleurBouton}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger  Property="ToggleButton.IsPressed" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CouleurBoutonPressed}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="UIElement.IsEnabled" Value="False">
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" Value="{StaticResource CouleurSecondaireDisabled}"/>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource CouleurSecondaireDisabled}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ItemsControl.IsGrouping" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="False"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="ComboBox.IsEditable" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="KeyboardNavigation.IsTabStop" Value="False"/>
                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="PART_EditableTextBox" Value="Visible"/>
                            <Setter Property="UIElement.Visibility" TargetName="ContentSite" Value="Hidden"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

my combobox :

```
<ComboBox  Style="{DynamicResource StyleComboBox}" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,5" Name="comboBox1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="200" />
```

And when I launch my application I always get the error :

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ItemsControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=VerticalContentAlignment; DataItem=null; target element is 'TreeViewItem' (Name=''); target property is 'VerticalContentAlignment' (type 'VerticalAlignment')
```

I tried to add the solution found on every subject : set horizontalcontentAlignement and VerticalContentAlignment. But it doesn't seem to change anything.

Could you help me on this one ?

Also, is there a way to make wpf write more detailed traces ?

(I've seen solutions saying I should just disabled wpf tracing but I'd rather correct the error)

Thank you !

Comment: It says `target element is 'TreeViewItem'` do you have any TreeViews there?

Comment: No, I don't have any, just 2 textblocks, 1textbox et 2 combobox into a grid.

Comment: But it doesn't complain about comboboxes. What you can do is delete everything from the window, make sure it runs without exceptions and add elements one by one (you may split you styles into several chunks). Thus you will see what exactly causes the problem.